# How to loop with FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to loop in vba with FormulaR1C1, but when I put the "R4C(15+i)" the result breaks on the front.

The VBA Formula im placing:

```
For i = 1 To 20
 Range("O5").Offset(0, i) = "=SumIfs(C10,C2,R5C15,C6,R4C(15+i))"
Next
```

The result Im getting on the front:
Its in spanish, but the important part is the part that dosent work at the end "@W$4(15+@i)".

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($J:$J,$B:$B,$O$5,$F:$F,@W$4(15+@i))
```

Comment: try `Range("O5").Offset(0, i) = "=SumIfs(C10,C2,R5C15,C6,R4C(" & 15+i & "))"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
For i = 1 To 20
    Range("O5").Offset(0, i) = "=SumIfs(C10,C2,R5C15,C6,R4C" & (15+i) & ")"
Next
```